# Converting a Python project to DLL or decreasing the size and imports

Tags: python, c#, pyinstaller, cython

I have a python project for OCR MRZ detection with 2 modules 1 is for ID which uses EasyOcr,pythorch and other one is for Passport documents which uses Pytesseract and tensorflow.
I need to prepare this project for deployment I have tried some methods but none of them was practible for deployment process.

- I have tried pyinstaller with couple of configurations with --onefile
  option the setup is great but it takes too long to unpack the exe
  when executed.
- I have then tried --onedir option the delay was gone but now
  installation package was too complicated and size was too
  large(1.8GB).
- I have tried to "compile" python code by using Cython but even with a
  helloworld.py sample app I couldn't manage to make this one work I
  got couple of errors during gcc compiling the last error I got due to
  msvcp package which i have installed but still got the error.
- And as last I have used Nuitka to get a dll-like file to import this
  in C# and use it like a package, I have successfully created a test
  .pyd file from a helloworld.py but i couldn't import it in C# as i
  planned.

What I need is to prepare this project as a simpler and low-sized application which is hard to reverse-engineered for source codes ready for deployment. For passport OCR I can switch development to C# but for ID I couldn't find any alternative OCR library to get the MRZ information so at least I need to use ID OCR module from my Python project.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Cython isn't designed for and isn't suitable for trying to deploy an application as a single file. You simply shouldn't use it for this task.

Comment: Doesn't need to be a single file but maybe more organized then PyInstaller because it just imports every library inside the application folder.

Comment: Cython is designed to generate single modules at a time for to interface with C/C++ code or write faster Python code. It isn't a packaging solution at all. It can be used with things like PyInstaller of course

Comment: Cython is not the only option I don't have much knowledge about packaging a Python project for deployment so what I ask is what is the best option for performing this task. The important points are performance, simplicity for installation, size of installation and keeping the project obfuscated.